# Qt, how to build a project with different parts

Tags: c++, qt, build

I am new to Qt.
I downloaded the Qt 4.8.6 on Mac, and wanted to try to build the address book example in `{QtProject}/examples/tutorials/addressbook` I cd to the addressbook directory, then entered command

`qmake -project
qmake
make`

It gave me error.

```
duplicate symbol __ZN11AddressBook11findContactEv in:
    addressbook.o
ld: 98 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [addressbook.app/Contents/MacOS/addressbook] Error 1
```

I looked into the files, there are 7 parts in the address book directory, and each contains a `main.cpp`.

I readed the **`README`**, it says

```
On Linux/Unix:

Typing 'make' in this directory builds all the programs (part1/part1,
part2/part2, part3/part3 and so on). Typing 'make' in each subdirectory
builds just that tutorial program.
```

How should I build the whole project please? I want to write a Qt program which could have dialogs with different tabs of layers, similar to the dialog you see when connecting to an odbc on Windows. So, I think I would need multiple dialogs with events connected among one another.

Thank you so much. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run `qmake -project`. By that you generate a new `.pro` and overwrite the current one. Recover the original `addressbook.pro` from the source archive and run only:

```
qmake
make
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much, this compiles the file. Before I accepting your answers, could you please tell me where I could access the executable file please? I mean, like how to run the program. Thanks so much! = )

Comment: You should be able to find one in every subdirectory. This tutorial contains seven parts. On Linux run it as `part1/part1`, on OSX it would be `open part1/part1.app`.

Comment: It's in part1.app/Contents/MacOSX/part1 But how do I track the events flow in the 7 parts please? Or are they separate projects at all?  Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by tracking? There is no explicit use of events in either of the parts. They are separate projects, all belong to address book tutorial. In every part there some new feature gets added. You should probably follow the tutorial http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/tutorials-addressbook.html